# Is introducing a where condition into the join clause bad practice

Tags: best-practices

In the query below, the condition

```
and r.master_seq=206
```

is used on the on clause as a join condition. 
In the programme code, the value for `r.master_seq` is set by a parameter.

My concern is that I'm not sure if it's ok to mix in this condition(r=.master_seq=123, that I believe should be a where condition) into the join condition.
I was thinking that I should only use relational information(primary keys and foreign keys) in the join clause, not a where condition ( where id=123, balance>300, etc).

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
TB_REQUEST_DATA D

left outer join
TB_SPOT_REPORT_REQUEST r
on D.SEQ = r.REQUEST_SEQ  
and r.master_seq=206

WHERE
  d.SEQ IN (
  7,12,5,11,4
  )


desc tb_request_data;
Name          Null     Type          
------------- -------- ------------- 
SEQ           NOT NULL NUMBER        
REQUEST_NM    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
REG_DT        NOT NULL DATE          
REG_ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
UP_DT         NOT NULL DATE          
UP_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
DISASTER_TYPE          VARCHAR2(500) 

desc TB_SPOT_REPORT_REQUEST;
Name         Null     Type          
------------ -------- ------------- 
MASTER_SEQ   NOT NULL NUMBER        
SEQ          NOT NULL NUMBER        
REQUEST_SEQ  NOT NULL NUMBER        
REAL_FILE_NM          VARCHAR2(100) 
DOWN_FILE_NM          VARCHAR2(100)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting a condition in the `WHERE` clause and the `ON` clause are two very different things.  The `ON` clause is part of the `JOIN`.  Now with an `INNER JOIN` you won't see any difference in the output (unless also using [`GROUP BY ALL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967048/73226)).  But an `OUTER JOIN` is a different story.  If you moved that particular condition into the `WHERE` clause it would (among other things), in effect, negate the `OUTER` portion of your query.

I wrote an article with several examples [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/93039/).

Just remember that the `ON` clause joins the two tables together.  The `WHERE` clause excludes rows from the output.  For your specific example lets say you have a row in `TB_REQUEST_DATA` without a match in `TB_SPOT_REPORT_REQUEST`.  With r.master_seq=206 in the `ON` clause of the  `OUTER JOIN` you will get a row returned with the value of `TB_REQUEST_DATA` but `NULLs` in the `TB_SPOT_REPORT_REQUEST` columns.  If on the other hand you put it in the `WHERE` clause it's going to eliminate the row entirely.

Let's say however that you want every row of `TB_REQUEST_DATA` but only the information in `TB_SPOT_REPORT_REQUEST` where master_seq = 206 **AND** SEQ = REQUEST_SEQ.  That's when you would put the condition in to the `ON` clause.

Comment: As for your link, is there any way I can read it without registering on that website? I'm sorry to ask you this but I don't see any close button on the modal popup.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it.  I can tell you from experience though that there aren't really any downsides to SSC.  You won't even get any emails if you don't want them.

Comment: @Ascendant http://bugmenot.com/view/sqlservercentral.com